# How to filter objects by properties in an array in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an element which is an array. I want to show the title of one of this objects by filtering in the array. Like:

```
<p>{{ element | myFilter:'type':'Type1').title }}</p>
```

So I tried to create an pipe filter:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'myFilter',
    pure: false
})
export class MyFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], filter: Object): any {
        if (!items || !filter) {
            return items;
        }
        return items.filter(item => item.title.indexOf(filter.type) !== -1);
    }
}
```

But that didn't work.

My array:

```
[
      {
       "type": "Type1",
       "title": "Message 1"
      }, 
      {
       "type": "Type2",
       "title": "Message 2"
      }
]
```

And what I want to show is the title of type 1. Like:

`<p>{{ element | myFilter:'type':'Type1').title}}</p>`

How to do this in Angular?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8a1hxc?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: do you want to filter using just type?

Comment: actually broad, so you can also filter by title or a property that is added later

Comment: @Can What type does `Array.prototype.filter` return? Does it return a single object or an array? If it's an array, can you access a property such as `title` doing `[{ id: 1, title: 'foo' }].title`? Or do you need to loop over the items or get an item via an index? If you looking for an array method that returns a single item, use `Array.prototype.find` instead.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky It will return a single item, so find is working now! Thanks. But Need to understand how to use multiple properties instead of 'type' .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the data incorrectly into the pipe, also the brackets are placed incorrectly. You should fix the brackets and just pass the data as a string:

```html
<p>{{ (element | myFilter: 'Type1').title }}</p>
```

Also you are filtering your pipe on the wrong property. With the updated data input for the pipe it should simply be:

```
export class MyFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], filter: string): any {
    if (!items || !filter) {
      return items;
    }
    return items.find(item => item.type === filter);
  }
}
```

Comment: What type does `Array.prototype.filter` return? Can you access a property such as `title` directly on an array like `[{ id: 1, title: 'foo' }].title`? Or do you need to either loop or access the object via an index? Perhaps there is another array method such as `find` that would return a single item?

Comment: `filter` returns the type that has been put into it. In this case that is `{type: string, title: string }`, as you can see from the array that is defined as input in the question.

Comment: @tommueller not working, I get also an error now on the `(filter.type)` part in the pipe. Error: `Property 'type' does not exist on type 'Object'.`

Comment: Ah you are passing a string, of course. I updated the answer

Comment: The pipe returns an array of items that match the type provided. That's what `Array.prototype.filter` returns, an array. You cannot access a property of an object in array directly. Do `element | myFilter: {type:'Type1'} | json` to see.

Comment: still not showing the title... empty 

first I saw the json object, but now it's empty.

Comment: please provide a stackblitz then, that makes helping a lot easier

Comment: @tommueller posted a Stackblitz link in the first post.

Comment: @Can Here is a fixed stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qirdah?file=src/app/app.component.html
I simplified the code a bit and will update the answer

Comment: @tommueller thanks this works! 

And what do I need to change if I want to use this pipe for multiple properties instead of 'Type' only?

Comment: You change the input of the pipe back to an object, and then do your filter logic depending on the object.

Comment: @tommueller changed the pipe to an object and used the object to filter with `{{ (element | myFilter: {type: 'Type1'}).title}}` didn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223640/discussion-between-can-and-tommueller).

Answer (score -1):

The way you are passing your filter object to the pipe is incorrect. You are passing strings.

Use like this:

```html
<p>{{ (element | myFilter: {'type':'Type1'})?.title }}</p>`
```

Also a `(` is missing from the start of your statement

Comment: @Can you are filtering incorrectly, check updated code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8a1hxc?file=src/app/myFilter.pipe.ts